# Preview option for entity registration form

Tags: entities

Is there a way to display preview before submission using [Entity Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/registration)?

Similar functionality as there is with node submit option. So that user can make changes if anything is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I have one another option that i have used:

```
function your_Module_name_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
   if ($form_id == 'your_form_id') { 
       $form['submit']['#attributes'] => array('class' => array('upersubmit'),'onclick' => 'if(!confirm_vil(this.id)){return false;}');
   }
```

}

/* Js Function in your js file */

```
function confirm_vil(val){
    /* Now here you can add popup code to view all data before submit */
}
```

i hope this is help you..

Comment: This is tricky as I have 4 different types of registration form for my site. Thanks for idea though

Answer (score 0):

As i know drupal don't have any module for this, you have to create custom module for this. in which you can view all data into popup before submit..

Comment: I even could not find a module, so added a question here. If one has idea. Making own custom module is finally an option.